# How to connect ComboBox to database file in C# for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, combobox, binding

I am learning how to use C# in visual studio, and now trying to connect a comboBox to a database file with extension .mdb
the combobox still can not get any information from the database.
I want to the combobox to display anything, description or loadid
and i will continue from there.

this is the XAML code

```
<Window x:Class="test_chose_pic.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test_chose_pic"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid Background="OldLace">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="390" Height="24" Background="Beige" >
    <Label Content="select:" Height=" 22" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        <ComboBox  x:Name="ComboBoxZone" Width="120" Height="22" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Margin=" 26,0" x:Name="btnZone"  Content="Show"  Width="70" Height="20" Click="btnZone_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

and the Code:

```
 public void BindComboBox(ComboBox comboBoxName)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = C:\Users\Mohammed's PC\Desktop\SCEPTER\pacificorpv07_2013.mdb;");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select loadid,description FROM load", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "laods");
        comboBoxName.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        comboBoxName.DisplayMemberPath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["loads"].ToString();
        comboBoxName.SelectedValuePath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["loadid"].ToString();
    }


    private void btnZone_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Selected ZoneName=" + ComboBoxZone.Text + " and ZoneId=" + ComboBoxZone.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }
```

for more clarity The database file have table called loads
and that table have two column called (loadid) and (description)

Comment: Are you using Access database? because  .mdb file format is for access database and in the code you have used sqlconnection i.e for sql server database.I think you should look for Oledb.

Answer (score 0):

The values for `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` properties of a wpf combobox will be column names/property names of the collection that you are used to bind the control. Here in your case you are using a DataTable, so the these values should be the name of the columns in the table. so change the following lines :

```
 comboBoxName.DisplayMemberPath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["loads"].ToString();
 comboBoxName.SelectedValuePath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["loadid"].ToString();
```

To this:

```
 comboBoxName.DisplayMemberPath = "loads";
 comboBoxName.SelectedValuePath = "loadid";
```

Comment: I did that but still the box does not show any data, i actully think the SQL connection isn't working right

Comment: @mohammadism: ok then check that first, is that dataTable is populated?

Comment: yeah i am trying to do that, but still not sure if the connection is right

Comment: First write a program to test the database. When you are sure that this is working and you understand it then write a program to test you know how to use combo boxes but don't try to connect the database. When you are sure you know how to get both combo boxes and databases working then try to connect them. Trying to do too much at once makes it hard to find the problem.